# Should I prefer "truncate" or "delete from" to remove contents of a table?

Tags: database

I just discovered that `"truncate {table}"` statements are not caught by most database triggers.
Am I taking any risks in terms of performances by replacing such statements by `"delete from {table}"` ?

I am particularly interested in MSSQL and Sybase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DELETE will be *a lot* slower and heavier on resources as proper transaction logs are created. But you can make it part of a bigger transaction, and, as you say, triggers and constraints will be activated, too.

TRUNCATE is considered a DDL operation, just like DROP TABLE. It is very fast, but cannot be done as part of a transaction (i.e. you cannot rollback).

Which one you need depends on your requirements. Do you have triggers that need to run? If so, can you maybe do something instead after or before the TRUNCATE to compensate for them not running?

Comment: [Truncate can be rolled back in SQL Server at least](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7677/3690). Not sure about Sybase.

Comment: @MartinSmith: +1. Seems my Oracle-based knowledge does not apply here... Will delete this answer as soon as another one is accepted.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think I found at last a reference in the [Sybase Online: Sybase ASE 15.7](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug832.htm). It only says: ***"Do not use these commands inside a transaction: alter database... (list of various commands) ... truncate table "***

Answer (score 2):

Truncate can be rolled back in SQL server but not in Sybase. If you have FK references by other tables to this table then you can not use trauncate table.

If you have logic in trigger like say to audit the data or delete the data from other tables based on this delete. You should stick to the delete but if you do not have any kind of triggers then best way would be truncate table.

Comment: This page claims that in newer version of Sybase, `TRUNCATE` can be rolled back: [What is the difference between Delete and Truncate command?](http://sybase-ase.blogspot.gr/2011/07/what-is-difference-between-delete-and.html)

Comment: Read the sybase manual and look for ddl in tran database option.You cant even put the truncate table command as part of transaction and thus rolling back is not at all possible.Read the manuals of vendor they provide quite a good info.http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp

Comment: In sybase it is considered as DDL.Just search for ddl in tran database option in sybase ase you will get your answers.